# How to convert a "Date" type array to a "String" type array (VB)

Tags: vb.net

My Code:

```
listDates = (From row In ds.Tables(0) Select row.Field(Of Date)("Check In")).ToList
arrDates = listDates.ToArray
        
  For a = 0 To arrDates.Length - 1
     arrDatesStr(a) = (arrDates(a)).ToString
  Next
```

I am making an analytics form to find the most popular month for a hotel:

- listDates is a list that stores all of the dates from the database
- arrDates is the conversion of listDates to an array
- arrDatesStr is the array I need to fill with the date values but as strings, so i can substring the month

I have checked the values in listDates and arrDates and they conversion is successful, but when I try to convert it to string it says

> "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

How do I convert arrDates to a string and input those values into arrDatesStr?

Comment: Main issue aside, why do you need to convert the list to an array?  Why not just iterate the list directly?  And where are you constructing arrDatesStr().  What is the purpose of arrDateStr() when it's a pretty simple task to output the date direct from the list?

Comment: Why call `ToList` on your query and then `ToArray` on your list? Why not just call `ToArray` on your query?

Comment: @Hursey Wish I knew why, but the program just crashes when it's directly set to an array. And I use arrDateStr() to store the dates as string so i can substring the month value and find the modal month so i can output the most popular month in the analytics form

Comment: There are many functions on the DateTime class specifically for extracting individual parts.  Take a look at the Month function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arrDatesStr(a)` has not been initialized.

You can add something like `dim arrDatesStr(arrDates.length-1)` before you use `arrDatesStr`. Better yet, don't use `arrDates` at all:

```
  For a = 0 To listDates.Length - 1
     arrDatesStr(a) = listDates(a).ToString
  Next
```

If you use date.month instead of substring to get the month, you won't have to worry about whether it's a 1 or 2 digit month, and you won't have to convert it to string.

```
m = listDates(a).Month
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it finally works correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a good reason not to, you should let the conversion create the array for you:

```vb
Dim dateStrings = Array.ConvertAll(dates, Function(dt) dt.ToString())
```

or:

```vb
Dim dateStrings = dates.Select(Function(dt) dt.ToString()).ToArray()
```

That will create a `String` array of the appropriate length, containing the appropriate data.

Note that the first option requires an array but the second option will work on any `IEnumerable(Of Date)`, which includes the `List(Of Date)` or even the original query.